# @Validated group error : No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer

Tags: java

I want to perform group validation on request parameters， so I use **@Validated annotaion**,but i got this error: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer

I think the problem happens with my custom annotation, **@Number**
Here is the implement of @Number

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = NumberValidator.class)
public @interface Number {

    String message() default "整数值不符合预期";

    /**
     * params[1]对应field name
     *
     * @return
     */
    String[] params() default {"", ""};

    /**
     * max value include
     *
     * @return
     */
    long max() default Long.MAX_VALUE;

    /**
     * min value include
     *
     * @return
     */
    long min() default Long.MIN_VALUE;

    /**
     * is allowed null?
     *
     * @return
     */
    boolean nullable() default false;

    /**
     * value enum
     */
    String[] values() default {};

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}

class NumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Number, java.lang.Number> {

    private long     max;
    private long     min;
    private boolean  nullable;
    private String[] values;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Number num) {
        max = num.max();
        min = num.min();
        nullable = num.nullable();
        values = num.values();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(java.lang.Number value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            if (nullable) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        if (values != null && values.length > 0) {
            return Arrays.asList(values).contains(value.toString());
        }
        return value.longValue() <= max && value.longValue() >= min;
    }
}
```

controller:

```
   public HttpResponse<AdPositionParamVO> create(@RequestHeader("x-ub-userId") Long ucId,
                                                @RequestBody @Validated(CreateAction.class) AdPositionParamVO param) {
```

VO:

```
    @Number(values = {"33", "34", "36", "44", "52"},  groups = CreateAction.class)
    @NotNull( groups = CreateAction.class)
    protected Integer adType;

    @Valid
    private AdInfo adInfo;
```

AdInfo:

```
    @Number(values = {"1", "2"},  groups = {CreateAction.class, UpdateAction.class})
    private Integer cpAdScene;
```

where is the problem？